# How to change the way the Default text in the Text editor is presented

Tags: android-studio

**This is how it`s presented:**

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/hatimage"
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**How I`d would like it to be:**

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/hatimage"
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win

```
Ctrl + Alt + L
```

Linux:

```
Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L
```

Mac:

```
Option + Command + L
```